# Cosmic Ray Detection | Fluorescent Light Bulbs

Tags: electronics, cosmic-rays, sensor

Main: Can cosmic rays be detected through fluorescent bulbs?

Can you push an AC current through a fluorescent lightbulb tube and measure the current draw and voltage spikes to detect cosmic rays? Is there another easy and affordable way to detect them? Other than a cloud chamber?

Comment: "Other radiation detectors can be used like Geiger Counters, Spark Chambers, Resistive Plate Chambers and materials called Scintillators which give off light when an ionizing particle passes through them.
The problem using a radiation detector for a cosmic ray observation is that there is larger amounts of terrestrial radiation as much 73% of background radiation is due to the natural decay of matter. Although in small quantities it is sufficient to make it difficult to discriminate between a terrestrial or cosmic source." from http://hardhack.org.au/book/export/html/2

Comment: Yes, hardhack has a page about detecting atmospheric muons using fluorescent tubes (and other methods): http://hardhack.org.au/detector-outline

Answer (score 2):

One would not use AC for that. It is easier with high-voltage DC, I would not know how to do the coincidence electronics otherwise. Pasco sells a setup with Geiger-Müller tubes:
https://www.pasco.com/prodCatalog/SF/SF-7278_complete-muon-observatory/index.cfm

Here is an overview of DIY projects: https://quarknet.fnal.gov/toolkits/ati/crdetectors.html

Fluorescent tubes can offer a larger detection area for a low price. Here someone who built a number of versions: https://www.astroparticelle.it/muon-detector2_eng.asp
(the version in Italian may be clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

While this is a lot more expensive, cosmic rays can be easily detected with optical fluorescence and/or using Cherenkov radiation. One does need a large area photomultiplier tube for that, though, which can be costly (unless you can get a used one in working condition). The only other ingredient is a large volume of water that is shielded really well against light. An oil barrel (maybe additionally wrapped in a few layers of black plastic foil) will probably do just fine for that.